# Query or filter on Fusion Tables?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

this a question from a very inexperienced user.
I have a table with electoral results, with this format:
[image: table example]

I have merged this table with city shapes and can do a map visualization according to one of the columns.
My problem comes when I want to do filters and queries. I am quite puzzled.

I know how to activate and deactivate layers from an html document, calling (showing and hiding) different fusion tables.

What I want to try now is using a sole fusion table for different ways to show the data. I don't know if this is possible.

For example, possible queries to show on different maps called from a html page:

1. show only rows with type (column H) 'rural' (filter?)
2. fill polygons with colours according to the greater value among column B, D and F (if value for party1_2012 is > than party 2 2012 and > than party 3 2012, polygon colour is blue; if party 2 wins, fill is red...)
3. fill polygons with colours according to the difference between 2 columns (i.e. 2010 and 2012 results)
4. map combining option 1 (when showing only rural city), apply option 3 (show a colour according the difference between 2 columns)

Inspired by John Keefe's post [Making AP Election Data Easy with Fusion Tables](http://johnkeefe.net/making-ap-election-data-easy-with-fusion-tabl), tried to play with data, but no luck. I'm too inexperienced. Is it the way to go generate csv and call them from a webpage? Can I just generate the maps on Fusion Tables and obtain a url to call the queried mapfrom a webpage?

I appreciate suggestions or ways to go.

Thanks in anticipation!

Frans